# Print YAML String with Shellscript

Tags: shell, yaml

I have the follow script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
test(){
  ENV="$1"

  if [[ $ENV == "dev" ]]; then
    echo "kind: ConfigMap
      apiVersion: v1
      metadata:
        name: test-app
      data:
        application.properties: |-
          param1=tcp://amq1:61616
          param2=tcp://amq2:61616
          param3=tcp://amq3:61616"
  fi
}

test $1
```

When I run this script I get the output with wrong YAML indentation:

```
vitor@thinkpadt480:~$ ./test.sh dev
kind: ConfigMap
      apiVersion: v1
      metadata:
        name: test-app
      data:
        application.properties: |-
          param1=tcp://amq1:61616
          param2=tcp://amq2:61616
          param3=tcp://amq3:61616
```

Is there any way to keep the YAML indentation from String without break the script indentation like this:

```
test(){
  ENV="$1"

  if [[ $ENV == "dev" ]]; then
    echo "kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: test-app
data:
  application.properties: |-
    param1=tcp://amq1:61616
    param2=tcp://amq2:61616
    param3=tcp://amq3:61616"
  fi
}
```

**EDIT**

With Here Document:

```
test(){
  ENV="$1"

  if [[ $ENV == "dev" ]]; then
    cat <<-YAML 
    kind: ConfigMap
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: ${ENV}
    data:
      application.properties: |-
        param1=tcp://amq1:61616
        param2=tcp://amq2:61616
        param3=tcp://amq3:61616
YAML
  fi
}

vitor@thinkpadt480:~$ ./test.sh dev
    kind: ConfigMap
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: dev
    data:
      application.properties: |-
        param1=tcp://amq1:61616
        param2=tcp://amq2:61616
        param3=tcp://amq3:61616
```

I don't if my understanding is right, but I need to use a delimiter, but only works if I place the end delimiter in line start.
And another point that he keeps the indentation since line start, this is the right behavior?

Comment: Use a here document: [3.6.6 Here Documents](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents)

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question.

Comment: Only leading *tabs* are stripped from here documents, not arbitrary whitespace. The `YAML` may also be tab-indented.

Comment: Also, YAML is a superset of JSON, so a tool like `jq` could be used to generate valid YAML in a more script-friendly fashion. (I understand there are more YAML-specific tools available as well, but I'm not familiar with any of them.)